# Load FlowPlayer video dynamically into asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, flowplayer

I tried passing in the name of the file via querstrying but it looks like flowplayer wants to load it before the Request.Querstring["videoName"] value is retrieved.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your asp.net page generate the clip configuration dynamically.  It's hard to be more specific without seeing your code.

http://flowplayer.org/documentation/configuration/clips.html